# Additional downloads from Google Play as needed

Tags: android, audio, google-play, android-developer-api

I have developed an App and now the users want the Audio files for it. If I add the audio it will be around 800mb, which is unacceptable. The app has multiple chapters and I am thinking of giving links to audio files of each chapter so that the user can download them individually as needed. They could delete them if short on storage.

I have looked into Android's expansion files but it's only a single file. What other options do I have to achieve this. The app is free without ads and I do not want to host the audio on my servers.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that's it. Put them in a file sharing space and let users handle downloading.

Comment: I do not want to host it myself, do you know any other options.

Comment: They are limited if they exist, but sorry I can't think of anything else. It would be advised since YOU would have control of the system. You don't have to have a server, just a cloud space that they could access with a link or something.